# Parsing decimal with thousands separator

Tags: c#, globalization

I have the following block of code:

```
string price = "1,234.56";
decimal value = 0;
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands);

if (Decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
{
    Console.log("Thank you!");
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidFormatException();
}
```

Ultimately, `price` will either be in US style (i.e. 1,234.56) or German style (i.e. 1.234,56). My challenge is right now, `Decimal.TryParse` fails. I suspect its because of the thousands separator. Which is why I added the `allowedStyles` variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try passing the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` instead of the `InvariantCulture` as the third parameter. This will make `TryParse` adapt to the locale of the current machine.

Comment: @CompuChip: I am not quite sure. Usually the use of `InvariantCulture` is intentional.

Comment: If you are parsing currency, how about `NumberStyles.Currency`?

Comment: Are you getting the input from a backend system or from a user?
If you are getting input from a backend under your control, you should standardize on a single format--InvariantCulture is an appropriate way to do that. If you have no control over the format, hopefully there is some higher level protocol that lets you know whether you are using DE or US or you will have ambiguities (these can be mitigated by a regex that is tighter than what Decimal.Parse accepts that can select the appropriate culture). Input from a user should use CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you **AND**-combine the `NumberStyles`-flag, you will get `None`.

```
00100000 (AllowDecimalPoint)
&
01000000 (AllowThousands)
--------
00000000 (None)
```

Try to **OR**-combine them: `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands`

```
00100000 (AllowDecimalPoint)
|
01000000 (AllowThousands)
--------
01100000 (AllowDecimalPoint, AllowThousands)
```

Additionally, I'm afraid that you can't parse **both** styles (US style and DE style) with **one** statement.

So I'd try both:

```
string price = "1,234.56";
decimal value = 0;
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);

if (Decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("DE-de"), out value))
{
    Console.Write("Danke!");
}
else if (Decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-us"), out value))
{
    Console.Write("Thank you!");
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidFormatException();
}
```

Comment: It's still ambiguous when you attempt to parse both unless it actually has both a decimal separator and a thousand separator. (12,34.56 will still parse with en-US so is 12,34 1234 or 12.34?)

Comment: That's right, if you have a number like `134.567` you just cannot know if `.` is the thousand separator or the decimal separator. It's easier with `12,34.56` because you can't have decimal separator before thusand separator - so `,`has to be thousand separator in that case. Nevertheless, there are scenarios where you are unable to determine which style is given.

Answer (score 1):

The result of this binary `and` (`&`) will always be `0` (`false`, or `NumberStyles.None`). That's why it doesn't allow decimal and thousand separators:

```
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Change to binary `or` (`|`):

```
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```