# Product Price returns fasle for is Modelstate Valid

Tags: c#

I have a **Class** Like below

```
class Product{
  public string ProductName {get;set;}
  public decimal ProductPrice {get;set;}

}
```

and in the **View** I refer the **model** at the top

and use `Lamba expression` to create the inputs

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Transaction.ProductName )
 @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.Transaction.ProductPrice )
```

Which all work, now when I input `1.11` into the product price it works fine

but if I enter something like `240,000` the `ModelState is not valid`

Why is that? what would be the correct way to do this? How do I create a textbox that only handles prices? and no text input?

Comment: because of the comma, comma is not a valid numeric value

Comment: well 1.11 and 1,11 differs, don't know if that would effect your code but maybe try it

Comment: @J.Steen yes, he / she can preformat the values before submitting the form using javascript. I'm not sure if that's the ideal way though

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a custom model binder for decimal datatype which will parse decimal values accordingly to your current culture:

```
public class PriceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = value };

        decimal result = 0.0M;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
            modelState.Errors.Add(new FormatException("Price is not valid"));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Using the `IModelBinder` is the correct approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem may be the comma in "240,000".  You have two options:

(a) limit the textbox to numerical characters only

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.TransactionProductPrice, new { type = "number" })
```

(b) change the type of ProductPrice to a string and then parse the string with a comma separating the thousands to a decimal on the controller end (see this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147178/parsing-decimal-with-thousands-separator) for help doing that)

```
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
var price = Decimal.Parse(viewmodel.TransactionProductPrice, allowedStyles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ,(comma) to .(dot) 

 In c# it uses .(dot) for decimal values(not the type, actual decimal values)
Rather use string formatting to convert your values from 2016000.5 to 2 016 000,5 or 2,016,000.5 if this is what you are looking for