# How to accept comma separator in Double parameter

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, double, separator

From View to Controller i want to send a field that contains a number that must be with this format: N,NNN. Problem it is that it makes error when it's sent to controller to double parameter, because it accepts only the dot. How can I change this setting?

```
 <div class=""><input type="text" value="0,000" id="volume" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Volume"> </div>
```

js:

```
 window.location.href = "/MyPrintLabelTest/StampaEtichetta/DownloadLabel?nColli=" + nColli + "&mittenteAlfa=" + mittenteAlfa + "&volume=" + volume; //PrintSuccess
```

Controller c#:

> public ActionResult DownloadLabel(int nColli, string mittenteAlfa,
> double volume) { .... }

Comment: How are you parsing it?

Comment: It would be nice to see the code. Please poste some then we can help you solving it better

Comment: And is that comma supposed to be the decimal mark, or a thousands separator?

Comment: Try to set current `CultureInfo` to *da-DK*. That culture using comma for decimal points.

Comment: @donggas90 I don't think OP wants to use the comma as a decimal point. I think they want it as a thousands separator.

Comment: @John Hmm, I don't think so. He said it is a double not an integer. And only accepts dots by default. It means that the string is a floating points.

Comment: @donggas90 Well, hopefully OP might come back and clarify their question.

Comment: If you want to parse thousands separator, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147178/parsing-decimal-with-thousands-separator) answers. Receive as string and try parse manually.

Comment: OP: And is , a thousands separator or a decimal point?

Comment: edited question. I mean decimal point. Format: N,NNN

Comment: I'd personally recommend having some kind of middleware to interpret the "Accept-Language" header and use that to set the request thread's culture. Then the user can input the number according to their own region.